# Excluding First and last rows from a sum window function in SQL

Tags: sum, aggregate-functions

I am executing the following query

```
SELECT QLID, 
       Emp_Date,
       Emp_Time,
       sum(emp_time) over(partition by qlid order by emp_time)
FROM GCC_INTERNAL_OPS.Entry_Time 
where (qlid='fs255015' or qlid='mf255005') 
    and emp_date=date '2013-01-31'
```

which returns the following resultset

```
QLID    Emp_Date    Emp_Time    Group Sum(Emp_Time)
FS255015    01/31/2013  1218    5390.00
FS255015    01/31/2013  1523    5390.00
FS255015    01/31/2013  1526    5390.00
FS255015    01/31/2013  1123    5390.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  0932    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  0936    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  1106    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  1332    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  1338    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  1348    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  1509    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  1544    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  1617    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  1639    15033.00
MF255005    01/31/2013  1732    15033.00
```

I want to exclude the first and last row in summation for each qlid. Any thoughts on how will I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
;with cte as
(SELECT e.*,
        row_number() over(partition by qlid order by emp_time) rna,
        row_number() over(partition by qlid order by emp_time desc) rnd
 FROM Entry_Time e
 where (qlid='fs255015' or qlid='mf255005') and emp_date='2013-01-31')
SELECT QLID, 
       Emp_Date, 
       Emp_Time, 
       sum(case when 1 in (rna,rnd) then 0 else emp_time end) 
          over(partition by qlid) conditional_sum
FROM cte
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ba07/3).